# How to manipulate the frame of an UIButton through its tag?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uibutton

I have created a couple of buttons programatically in code (in a for-loop). If the user touches and drags one of these buttons, I would like to animate the button frame and then delete it (so a bit like the behaviour of the normal OS X Dock if you kick out an app).

My problem is that I don't know how to access the frame of a button: I only have the tag of the button as this is everything passed on to the delete method. **How can I manipulate the frame if I only have the tag of a button?**

Here is my code so far:

```
for (int k=0; k < numberOfTabs; k++) // k < 4 (e.g. 3 < 4) 
    {
        UIButton* btn = [[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:frame] autorelease];
        btn.tag = k; 
        btn.frame = CGRectMake(-10, 0, buttonWidth, buttonHeight);
        [btn    addTarget:self
                action:@selector(tabAction:)
      forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [btn    addTarget:self
                    action:@selector(tabDelete:)
          forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragOutside];

...
```

And this is my tabDelete method so far:

```
-(void)tabDelete:(id)sender
{
    NSInteger tid = ((UIControl*)sender).tag;
    NSLog(@"buttonTag about to be deleted has the tag: %i", tid);



}
```

Comment: Put your buttons in an array.

Comment: In your delegate method, the `sender`parameter _is_ your button. You can access its `frame` property the same way you access its `tag`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cast the UIControl to a UIButton and you will have access to the frame, e.g.:

```
- (void)tabDelete:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
    CGRect frame = button.frame;
}
```

`-addTarget:action:forControlEvents:` on UIButton always provides the UIButton instance as sender.

**@albertamg**: thank you, fixed :)

Comment: I think you meant `UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;`